# How to use an iPhone as a USB Sound Card

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, iphone, sound-card

I know this is highly irregular... but this is actually what I am trying to do, you understood correctly...

I have a computer running Ubuntu 11.04 which does not recognize my earphones, and I cannot get to any other headphones at this time.  I want to, if possible, use the USB-to-iPhone tether to connect my iPhone to the computer and then plug my earphones into that and use the iPhone to hear the sounds output from the computer.

So kind of like the earphones were plugged directly into the computer, but not.

Is this possible?

Comment: Rather than pushing this over USB, would an acceptable alternative be to stream PC audio to the iphone over wifi?

Comment: Paul's solution would work. Why are you trying to do this? The only reason I can think of is if your sound card is not working, so Paul's solution would work.

Comment: Yes to both.  Yes that is my problem and yes that is a much better/easier/less complicated solution, I don't know why I didn't think of that... but remember, (not sure if this will change anything) I am using linux, not a mac

Answer (score 2):

> PocketAudio lets you use your iOS device as a wireless soundcard of your computer. PocketAudio automatically forwards audio captured or played on your computer to your iOS device.  You can use PocketAudio as a wireless headphones and/or wireless microphone for your computer.

http://www.senstic.com/iphone/pocketaudio/pocketaudio.aspx

(Should work on Windows and Mac OS X)

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to use an iPhone as a sound card device through USB because it is not a USB sound device. Even if you force your OS to use USB sound drivers to communicate with the iPhone, the iPhone would not know what to do with the instructions in the first place because it has to implement the appropriate interfaces, which it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this, maybe this might be helpful. You need a camera connection kit & some tweak installed on your phone.
http://youtube.com/watch?v=tSrIceOK7js

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.superuser.com/faq) for more info.